# disable chrome task manager? alternatively: prevent extensions from being killed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, script, process, google-chrome-extensions

I have installed the chrome extension "Stayfocusd" which blocks websites for a certain amount of time. However, I have noticed a way to get around this. If you go to Chrome Task Manager and kill the running extension, then one has access again to all the websites.

How can one avoid this trick? I thought about the following...

- prevent access to chrome task-manager by removing some menus in chrome and blocking out the shift+ESC shortcut
- disable/remove the task manager completely (which is probably not possible)
- run a script "inside" chrome which checks periodically if the task-manager is opened, and, whenever it is: kill it (cf. also [Removing or disabling Chrome’s Task Manager with a batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/682273/removing-or-disabling-chrome-s-task-manager-with-a-batch-file) which didn't really work for me)
- make a link between the main-process & sub-process, i.e. if the sub-process (extension) is killed, the main-process (chrome) must also be killed && if the main-process (chrome) starts the sub-process (extension) must also start

However, I don't have the necessary programming skills to undertake these suggestions.

Hopefully somebody can help me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you doing this? I ask because I can think of several different approaches depending on what you are trying to achieve. Is this because you have a compulsion as the plugin says it is used for? Is this because you don't want kids surfing the net when they should be doing homework? Is this because you are managing a network and want to prevent a lot of users from accessing a lot of sites?

Comment: OP, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So there seems to be no way around it, but there is Software called "cold turkey blocker", which can also block websites. In its settings there is an option which you can turn on and cold turkey recognizes when the extension has been disabled via task manager.

"Settings > Blocking and enable the feature to block supported browsers if the extension crashes."

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to disable the Esc + Shift shortcut for Chrome.

First one is to use AutoHotKey script. You need to download autohotkey program and then create an .ahk script. In the file you put this code:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#NoTrayIcon ; the process will not appear on windows taskbar on the right
+Esc:: ; Shift + Esc keys, if pressed: 
if WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe") ; if Chrome is opened:
{
    MsgBox don't ever open chrome's task manager ; don't react to hotkey but open a window and 
    SoundBeep, 750, 2000 ; after closing the window play a beep sound for two seconds at 750 herz
}
return ; makes sure all lines of code are done 
^q::ExitApp ; combination Ctrl + q ensures I can kill the process
```

first 4 lines of code do nothing important. Other lines I commented.

The second way to block the shortcut is to download  *AutoControl: Keyboard shortcut, Mouse gesture* extension for Chrome. Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-keyboard-shor/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd

Then in the extension page you choose for trigger Shift and Esc buttons and for action you choose nothing.

How to disable The Task manager button which can be accessed by `three vertical dots -> More tools -> Task manager` I didn't figured out.

But you will be less tempted to disable extensions that way as it requires more steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce the extension by opening Registry Editor and creating ExtensionInstallForcelist registry.

It should be located here:

> Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist

in it, you should create string and input your extension ID which you will find in chrome://extensions, and then add `;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`.

Consult https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=ExtensionInstallForcelist.